# What would be a suitable database schema for the following scenario?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, schema

I have newsid and keyword. Now i have a mapping of keywords to newsid's in a many to many fashion.
for eg

```
**keyword**     **Newsid**
FIFA           221,123,133
Stack          12,2
dragon         23,577,33
```

Also i have a mapping that  should store priority for each keywords for a particular user
for e.g.
Lets suppose user "mark" has the following keywords with priority  for him:-

```
**Keyword**     **priority**
apple           0.5
jeff jones      0.9 
sugar           0.3



Use cases 
1)to get all the news id that are mapped to a specific keyword 
2)to get all the keyword that are mapped to a specific news id
3)To increase the value of priority for keyword x by value y for user z
4)Retrieve the list of all keywords
5)add a new keyword r for user s with priority f
```

**Note that keywords are not predetermined and can increase to any number,So is the case with News and users.**

Flawed solution thus far
I have a database with the following structure

```
Table -News(newsid,story)
Table -Keyword(keyword,[list_of_news_id seprated by comma])
Table -User_preference(userid,[(keyword1 -priority1),(keyword2-priority2)...])
Table -User(userid,name)
```

The problem with my solution is that to query keyword mapped to a specific id i need to process all tuples of Keyword table.

Moreover to update the priority of a certain keyword for a certain user , I would have to first retrieve all keyword priority pair for him(since they are in a common column) and then select my desired keyword and manually change it using some text processing and replace the value with new one.

Please suggest me a suitable database schema that fulfills all my use case requirements and that doesn't need to alter the database schema each time with addition of new keywords/news/users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USER` can have **many** `KEYWORD`
`KEYWORD` can be used by **many** `USER`

So `USER` and `Keyword` has **many-to-many** relationship

---

`NEWS` can have **many** `KEYWORD`
`KEYWORD` can be used by **many** `NEWS`

So `NEWS` and `Keyword` has **many-to-many** relationship

---

### And if you use [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table):

**USER TABLE:**

```
ID | NAME |ETC..
```

**KEYWORD TABLE:**

```
ID | KEYWORD | DESCRIPTION | ETC...
```

**USER_KEYWORD TABLE:**

```
ID | USER_ID | KEYWORD_ID | PRIORITY
```

**NEWS TABLE:**

```
ID | TITLE | ETC...
```

**NEWS_KEYWORD TABLE:**

```
ID | NEWS_ID | KEYWORD_ID
```